# Free tool for graphical representations of XML files

Tags: windows, xml, text-editing, viewer

I need a tool which displays an XML file in a nice way.

With "nice way" I mean a way on which I can fold and unfold all the nodes.

Is there any free tool that runs on Windows Vista that does this trick?

Comment: Please specify which OS the tool needs to run on.

Comment: On Windows Vista. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) does the trick.

> Notepad++ is a free (as in "free
>   speech" and also as in "free beer")
>   source code editor and Notepad
>   replacement that supports several
>   languages.

[image]

---

**Some more features**

- Tabbed document interface
- Drag-and-drop
- Multiple Clipboard (plugin required)
- Split screen editing and synchronized scrolling
- Spell checker (requires Aspell) (Spell checker does not distinguish between text and code)
- Supports text encoding formats such as Unicode, for international writing systems
- Find and replace over multiple documents
- File comparison
- Zooming
- Syntax highlighting and syntax folding

Source: [Wikipedia - Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad++)

Answer (score 7):

I recommend the free [XML Marker](http://symbolclick.com/) version 1.1 - [download link](http://symbolclick.com/xmlmarker_1_1_setup.exe) (not the latest commercial version). Although version 1.1 has not been updated since 2004,
it is still entirely sufficient for most purposes.

[image]

Comment: +1 Not come across this app before - wish I'd known about it ages ago!

Comment: Interesting. Nice!

Comment: -1 for not saying it's NOT FREEWARE... and not even cheap: $125 for a 1-person licence.

Comment: @mikerodent: Verify before downvoting, I say "I recommend the **free XML Marker**". This version 1.1 is still freeware today and is still entirely sufficient for most purposes. I made it clearer above.

Comment: @harrymc abject apologies... upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

http://codebeautify.org/xmlviewer 
If you are looking for online tool then this may help Which supports image view.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide some additional information about the software rather than just a link.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of free tools that have collapsable nodes, Xeena and XML Marker are a few, there is a fuller list [here](http://www.xml-editor.info/free-xml-editor/). However you do get what you pay for so don't be too surprised if it's a bit clunky and unsophisticated. For something a bit better take a look at [Liquid XML Editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com).

Answer (score 1):

I recomend notepad++ too, but sometimes i use Internet Explorer to navigate on a XML file, ie can fold and unfold notes too.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's [XML Notepad 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7973) is also a handy little editor.